# Stripe client intergration not taking affect after I click buy now link

Tags: javascript, html, stripe-payments

I followed this documentation and my stripe checkout is not working. I have taken out the sku and pk from the SO snippet below but can anybody see what I have done wrong as I thought I implemented it correctly.

When I click the buy now link, nothing happens, don't even redirect to the checkout page.

```
HTML link:
<a class="buy-btn">Buy Now</a>

...

Javascript:

 <script>
        (function () {
            var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_xxx');

            var checkoutButton = document.getElementsByClassName('buy-btn');
            checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
                // When the customer clicks on the button, redirect
                // them to Checkout.
                stripe.redirectToCheckout({
                    items: [{ sku: 'sku_xxx', quantity: 1 }],

                    // Do not rely on the redirect to the successUrl for fulfilling
                    // purchases, customers may not always reach the success_url after
                    // a successful payment.
                    // Instead use one of the strategies described in
                    // https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfillment

                    successUrl: window.location.protocol + '//www.xxx-online.com/xxx-leap/success',
                    cancelUrl: window.location.protocol + '//www.xxx-online.com/xxx-leap/cancelled',

                })
                    .then(function (result) {
                        if (result.error) {
                            // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
                            // error, display the localized error message to your customer.
                            var displayError = document.getElementById('error-message');
                            displayError.textContent = result.error.message;
                        }
                    });
            });
        })();
```

Comment: It's hard to say with just the code and no other information. Have you look at your JS console in the browser? Is there any error there that could explain what's happening, such as Checkout not being enabled in the account or the success/failure URLs not being allowed?

Comment: +1 for the idea of troubleshooting. You need to isolate the problem by checking the browser console for JS errors and the Stripe console for other errors. Stripe can do ridiculously wacky stuff that results in weirdo HTTP responses. You need to identify the response you're getting before you can continue.

Comment: Ah fair enough, it says Uncaught TypeError: checkoutButton.addEventListener is not a function
    at (index):269
    at (index):294